# How to load data from remote URI with nestjs/axios properly using Observables in the correct way?

Tags: axios, nestjs, rxjs-observables

NestJs suggests to use the `HttpModule` imported from `@nestjs/axios` to perform requests to external APIs. I understand that the HttpService transforms the responses into Observables. However, it makes it hard to fetch data inside of my service that wants to fetch data from a remote service and immediately work with these data:

```
try {
  const metaData = await this.httpService.get(tokenUri).pipe(
    map((res) => res.data),
    catchError((e) => {
      throw new HttpException(e.statusText, e.status);
    }),
  );
  console.log("---------------")
  console.log(metaData);
  console.log("---------------")
} catch (e) {
  this.logger.error(`Unable to fetch MetaData from ${tokenUri}. ` + e.toString());
}
```

What I get is this:

```
---------------
Observable {
  source: Observable {
    source: Observable { _subscribe: [Function (anonymous)] },
    operator: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  operator: [Function (anonymous)]
}
---------------
```

The reason why I don't want to use `subscribe` directly after the execution of `get` is that this way I was not able to catch 404 errors. On the internet I found the combination of `pipe` and `catchError` in order to do so. This way I am able again to catch the errors but I don't get any data anymore.

Thus, I have still to execute `subscribe` to subscribe on my data.
So I came up with this:

```
this.logger.debug('Found Token-URI: ' + tokenUri);
try {
  const metaData = await this.httpService.get(tokenUri).pipe(
    map((res) => res.data),
    catchError((e) => {
      throw new HttpException(e.statusText, e.status);
    }),
  );

  metaData.subscribe((x) => {
    // here is my data:
    console.log(x);
  });
} catch (e) {
  this.logger.error(`Unable to fetch MetaData from ${tokenUri}. ` + e.toString());
}
```

This way it works, but I am not sure if it is the right way from the `nextjs/axios` developers point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you can simplify your code by using an error-handler that you can provide to the `.subscribe` function. So instead of having to use `try/catch` and rethrowing the error, you could simply do:

```
this.logger.debug('Found Token-URI: ' + tokenUri);

const metaData$ = this.httpService.get(tokenUri).pipe(map((res) => res.data));

metaData$.subscribe(
   (x) => console.log(x),
   (err) =>  this.logger.error(`Unable to fetch MetaData from ${tokenUri}. ` + e.toString())
);
```

As a side note, I'd recommend reading this [blog-post](https://blog.angular-university.io/rxjs-error-handling/) regarding rxjs error-handling.